# Drawing diamond of asterisks

Tags: java, object, asterisk

I have this program in which you input a number and it prints it into a diamond. I have the top half aligned and figured out, just cant get the bottom half aligned. It's supposed to go up in the number of asterisks and then go back down to one.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Diamonds
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int n, i, j, space = 0;
        System.out.print("Enter the number of rows: ");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = s.nextInt();
        space = n - 0;
        for (j = 0; j <= n; j++)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < space; i++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
                System.out.print("   ");
            space--;
            for (i = j; i <= 2 * j - 1; i++)
            {
                System.out.print("* ");
            }
            System.out.println("   ");
        }
        space = 0;
        for (j = n - 1  ; j > 0; j--)
        {
            for (i = 0; i <= i - n; i++)
            {
                System.out.print("   ");
            }

            System.out.print(" ");

            space--;

            for (i = j; i <= 2 * j - 1; i++)
            {
                System.out.print(" *");
            }
            System.out.println("  c ");
            space=n-1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (j = n - 1  ; j > 0; j--)` play with this. Start/end higher/lower and see how the result changes.

Comment: And it might be a good chances to learn [how to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score -1):

I moved your input into an option pane and cleaned up some of the other code:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    try {
        String amt = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of rows:");
        int n = Integer.valueOf(amt);
        int space = n;
        for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            IntStream.range(0, space).forEach(i -> builder.append(' '));
            builder.append("   ");
            space--;
            IntStream.range(j, 2*j).forEach(i -> builder.append("* "));
            System.out.println(builder);
        }
        space++;
        for (int j = n - 1; j > 0; j--) {
            space++;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            IntStream.range(0, space).forEach(i -> builder.append(' '));
            builder.append("   ");
            IntStream.range(j, 2*j).forEach(i -> builder.append("* "));
            System.out.println(builder);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: "I moved your input into an option pane" why?? And what did you do to solve the problem at hand? It's not clear.

Comment: Because I hate dealing with consoles when testing.  The method of input is irrelevant to the problem he's having.

Comment: Then what *is* relevant in your answer? As I said, it's not clear what you did that actually solves the problem.

Comment: The point is that while this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.